# Merge rows in Pandas dataframe based on common columns, while appending some fields

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Please excuse me if this is a very basic question I am a relative beginner with both Python and Pandas.

I have a csv file of observations and classifications. Each observation appears multiple times in the results as the classification is repeated using different training data, indicated by the "split_on" column. I wish to merge all instances of the same observation into a single row while retaining the different classification results, and additionally add columns for averages .

This is what a single observation looks like in the original form:

| datetime | bID | data1 | data2 | data3 | split_on | probability | prediction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50:03.3 | WI172 | 123 | 456 | 789 | group1 | 0.2 | class1 |
| 50:03.3 | WI172 | 123 | 456 | 789 | group2 | 0.4 | class1 |
| 50:03.3 | WI172 | 123 | 456 | 789 | group3 | 0.7 | class2 |
| 50:03.3 | WI172 | 123 | 456 | 789 | group4 | 0.2 | class1 |

And this is what it should look like after merging:

| datetime | bID | data1 | data2 | data3 | group1_prob | group2_prob | group3_prob | group4_prob | group1_pred | group2_pred | group3_pred | group4_pred | probabilityAvg | predictionAvg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50:03.3 | WI172 | 123 | 456 | 789 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.7 | 0.2 | class1 | class1 | class2 | class1 | 0.375 | class1 |

There are a few caveats:

- Observations do not necessarily have rows corresponding to all of the possible groups, so NaNs are expected and appropriate.
- The results file is around 10GB in size so I'm using the "chunksize" parameter with "load_csv", and I have to iterate over every chunk for each observation to make sure I have all the relevant rows.

I have written the following to achieve this:

```
import pandas as pd

group_cols = ["datetime", "bID"] #this is enough to uniquely identify a single observation

groups = set()

chunksize = 10 ** 6
#first pass over file collects a list of groups
for chunk in pd.read_csv("result.csv",
                         chunksize=chunksize, usecols=group_cols):
    chunkGroups = chunk.groupby(group_cols)

    for (groupLevels), chunkGroup in chunkGroups:
        groups.add(groupLevels)

rows = []
#now pass over file for each group to collect associated rows
for group in groups:
    result = []
    for chunk in pd.read_csv("result.csv", chunksize=chunksize):
        chunkGroups = chunk.groupby(group_cols)
        if group in chunkGroups.groups.keys():
            result.append(chunkGroups.get_group(group))

    result_df = pd.concat(result) #This dataframe contains all rows pertaining to a single observation

    result_df.set_index('split_on', inplace=True)

    probs=result_df['probability']
    probs.index += "_prob"
    preds=result_df['prediction']
    preds.index += "_pred"

    new_row = pd.Series(result_df.iloc[0].drop(['probability','prediction']))
    new_row = pd.concat([new_row,probs,preds])

#add a class label based on the average probability
    new_row['probability-avg'] = result_df['probability'].mean()
    if new_row['probability-avg'] > 0.5:
        new_row['predictedAspect-avg'] = "class2"
    else:
        new_row['predictedAspect-avg'] = "class1"

    rows.append(new_row)
    print('merged row: ', new_row)

rows_df = pd.concat(rows, axis=1,sort=True).transpose()

rows_df.to_csv("mergedResults.csv", index=False)
```

This works but the transformation is tremendously slow (a few seconds per row!),  and processing my whole file like this would take more time than I have.

Is there a more sensible way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pivot`:

```
from statistics import mode

k = df.pivot(index=['datetime', 'bID', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3'], columns=[
             'split_on'], values=['probability', 'prediction'])
k.columns = k.columns.map(lambda x: '_'.join(x[::-1]))

df = k.reset_index()

df['prediction_avg'] = df.filter(regex=r'.*_prediction').mode(1)
df['probability_avg'] = df.filter(regex=r'.*_probability').mean(1)
```

OUTPUT:

| datetime | bID | data1 | data2 | data3 | group1_probability | group2_probability | group3_probability | group4_probability | group1_prediction | group2_prediction | group3_prediction | group4_prediction | prediction_avg | probability_avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50:03.3 | WI172 | 123 | 456 | 789 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.7 | 0.2 | class1 | class1 | class2 | class1 | class1 | 0.375 |

Comment: This is great. Thank you